# Compression & Streaming for a Folder

Tags: c++, zip

I'm hosting a file server, where i'm allowing my client to download their files from Web Portal. I'm providing a Folder download request, which zips the folder in server side with the files in it and then it allows to download it as a single zip file. But when the folder is big, zip process takes some time and user is getting annoyed. I was looking for some compression with streaming support for Folder zip, but i couldn't get any. Any ideas ..?

My Current Procedure :
After restore in a temp location in my webserver,
zip -r FOLDER.zip FOLDER/
then the FOLDER.zip gets downloaded via webserver.

Is it possible to start serving the file from the temporary file zip creates or is there any streaming support in zip ..?

Comment: Would it not be a better option to simply save the compressed file, so that eventually, you have all the folders in a zipped version too. This of course assumes a) diskspace isn't an issue and b) folders don't change so often that each folder download is a "new" version c) you can determine if there are new files in the folder (scanning for files with a newer date than the zip file should do this quite cheaply).

Comment: @MatsPetersson  , that's not possible, user may request for any folder he like.

Comment: Of course it's possible. I'm sure your system doesn't have infinite disk-space, which in turn means there is only a finite number of possible folders.

Comment: @MatsPetersson , i'm running a server, thousands of users use it everday. Besides files are changing often. And how can i keep a zip of all folders, user may wish to download for any sub directory at anytime.The files i'm serving on a webserver are backed up from their machines, so each and every user's files are different.

Comment: So, in that case, it seems unlikely that you'll benefit from caching, since it sounds like a user will only ever download a set of files once. It may be a better idea to simply set the expectation by saying "This may take a little while". Or use zip to write to standard out (or a pipe or something like that) and then let that send to the other end.